# Calculating the distance between two points in same column python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two columns in csv file that I have imported to pandas dataframe. First column is latitude and Second column is longitude. For each lat, long, I want to find the distance between all the other coordinates in the column and return the location of the smallest distance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopy.distance
from math import sin,cos,sqrt,atan2,radians

df=pd.read_csv('coordinates.csv')
R=6373.0

df['coords']=list(zip(df['lat'],df['long'])
df['coords2']=list(zip(df['lat'],df['long'])
```

So, for each coordinate, I want to be able to find the smallest coordinate from all the others in the list, but my for loop below is just giving a long list of distances with no tracking of the location.

I have a distance function that takes 2 points:

```
def distance (p1, p2):
    return (geopy.distance.vincenty(p1,p2).km)

dist=[]
for i in range(0,len(df.coords)):
         for j in range(0,len(df.coords2)):
             if df.coords[i] != df.coords2[j]:
                 x=distance2(df.coords[i],df.coords2[j])
                 dist.append(df.coords[i], x)
```

Sample Data:

```
location lat            long
0        34.159525  -82.381883
1        33.57112   -81.761782
2        32.965361  -81.248054
3        34.511574  -82.646487
```

Output wanted:

```
   location lat         long         closest_distance
    0        34.159525  -82.381883   2
    1        33.57112   -81.761782   3
    2        32.965361  -81.248054   3
    3        34.511574  -82.646487   0
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `for` brute-force work? Depends how big the files are.

Comment: It's less than 100 rows long so small file. Do you have a sample of what that would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the function `distance` you defined works for when the two inputs are same (returning `0`), the following brute-forcing should work:

```
def foo(latlong, location=list(range(len(latlong))):
    closest_distance = []
    for i in latlong:
        dist = list(map(lambda x: distance(i,x), latlong))
        min = dist.sort()
        closest_distance.append(location[dist.index(min[1])])
    return closest_distance
```

`latlong` is a list of lattitude-longitude tuples, and location is a list of the names you choose to give these pairs, which from your writeup seemed like simple numbering.

Comment: Would this still work if my coordinates are in different columns. So for each coordinate in column 1, I want to find the closest coordinate to column2?

Comment: Yes. In the map, map the distance function to the other column. You'll need to pass the identifier for the other column to the location argument.